# Displaying Certain Text if Certain Image is Showing PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I need a certain Piece of text to show if a certain image is showing.

Currently I have this for the random background image:

```
<?php
// Time to do all the background stuffs 
  $bg = array('01.jpg', '02.jpg',  '04.jpg', '970.jpg', '294.jpg', '096.jpg', '05.jpg', '08.jpg', '011.jpg', '012.jpg', '035.jpg', '045.jpg', '049.jpg', '066.jpg', '079.jpg', '096.jpg', '106.jpg', '173.jpg', '178.jpg', '205.jpg', '372.jpg', '500.jpg', '513.jpg', '682.jpg', '714.jpg', '860.jpg', '895.jpg', '914.jpg', '939.jpg', '966.jpg', '1025.jpg', '1074.jpg', '1123.jpg', '1162.jpg', '1499.jpg' ); 
  // array of filenames
  $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); // generate random number size of the array
  $selectedBg = "$bg[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen
?>

<style type="text/css">
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yatra+One';
body{
background: #000000 url(images/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>) no-repeat;
background-position: center;
}

  </style>
```

This is to do the background and CSS for the background and I then have multiple quotes that need to show depending on the image.

Any Help is appreciated

Cheers Tom

Comment: So create array of quotes and do the same

Comment: @u_mulder How would I ensure that it's synced with the correct Image as well?

Comment: You use the same index `$i` or an associative array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As every quote depends on image - you should rebuild your array: key must be file name and value is a quote. After that you can do this:

```
// Time to do all the background stuffs 
$bg = array(
    '01.jpg' => 'I have a dream', 
    '02.jpg' => 'Don\'t ask yourself',  
    '04.jpg' => 'Bond. James Bond',
    // more 
);
$rand_key = array_rand($bg);
$rand_quote = $bg[$rand_key];
echo $rand_key, $rand_quote;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should add another array:

```
$bgText = array("01.jpg" => "text you wanna display when 01.jpg is selected", ...);
```

Then in where you want to display the text:

```
<?= $bgText[$selectedBg] ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution One:**

You need to create an array as key value pair so that you can commbine the image along with the text.

**Syntax:**

```
array(
    key  => value,
    key2 => value2,
    key3 => value3,
    ...
)
```

The comma after the last array element is optional and can be omitted. This is usually done for single-line arrays, i.e. array(1, 2) is preferred over array(1, 2, ). For multi-line arrays on the other hand the trailing comma is commonly used, as it allows easier addition of new elements at the end.

```
$image_text = array("light.png" => "Alternative Text for light.png", ...);
```

And in the display section you can display the data like this .

```
<?php
echo $image_text[$alt_text];
?>
```

**Solution Two:**

Like wise as you did for `bg` you can given the name of the variable as `alt` and you can provide the names in the array and you can print in the img tag that you have used.

**Exapmle:**

```
$alt=array('lilly','rose','apple');
```

Along with the bg image that you given in style you can add this line to to that div.

```
<body>
<?php echo $alt[1]; ?>
</body>
```

If the `bg` image is not displayed the alt will be seen.